# Is there any method to minimize images using webpack 5?

Tags: webpack, plugins

I am literally getting lost inside a ton of articles, youtube videos, documentation of plugins loaders trying to find a way to minimize the size of images in webpack. 
I need a way to do that with webpack 5 (with plugins loaders no problem). 
Thank you guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to minimize your images as static assets is to pass them though  [image optim](https://imageoptim.com/mac), so you can reduce their size by 70/80%. Then store them on a CDN such as Cloudinary and serve their url. This will greatly improve your client delivery time.

However, if you wish to compress your whole Webpack bundle, you can simply use the [webpack compression plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/compression-webpack-plugin), with gizp and brotli algorithms.

EDIT: you may also use [ImageMinimizerWebpackPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/image-minimizer-webpack-plugin/)

Comment: Thank you so much for this informations, but if there is any plugin or loader I can use to do the job it will be great in my case.

Comment: Yes, I've updated my comment.

Comment: If this answer satisfies you, please mark it as valid so other people can benefit from a solved thread.